# Make Pairing(Authentication) popup for Mi Band 3 using CoreBluetooth

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I want to read **Heart Rate, Sleep Data** from **Mi Band 3** and for that I need to **authenticate or make pairing popup** for that.
Here is pairing details:

```
let BLE_Pairing_Service_CBUUID = CBUUID(string: "0xFEE1")
let Pairing_Chars_UUID = CBUUID(string: "00000009-0000-3512-2118-0009AF100700")
```

I am using above details for reading characteristics. But i don't know to **generate authenticate popup**. Please help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So After a lot of efforts I got solution :

**Step:1**- For authentication **send 18 bytes** to the auth characteristics.
**Step:2**- Create array of 18 size means 18 bytes and **convert** it into `Data()` type.

**Step:3**- Now **write that 18 bytes data** in your peripheral.

```
if characteristic.uuid == Pairing_UUID {
                    let cmdBytes: [UInt8] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
                    let cmd = Data(cmdBytes)
                    peripheral.writeValue(cmd, for: characteristic, type: .withoutResponse)
                    peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
                }
```

write above code in `didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor` method.